# Implementing exclusive locks in Node.js Cluster

Tags: node.js, multithreading, locking, cluster-computing

I did create a simple API for some service using Node.js, and to get use of the multiple processors existing.

So, I did use the cluster module, but noticed through logs that some requests get repeated due to some client issue, which then allow duplicate processing through multiple workers at the same time.

I thought about implementing Exclusive Locks pattern, like the following:

1. Master is listening for messages from Workers, to Check, Create or Delete a lock.
2. Master is storing locks in an Object which is defined inside the Master ( Checking cluster.isMaster ).
3. Each worker receiving a request from a user is going to talk to the Master to check if a lock existing for a differen worker id, or not. If existing, it does end the request with suitable error message.
4. Each worker does send the Master a locking request including the worker id and user's unique id, so both of them are added to the Locks object in the Master.
5. Lock are cleared once the process is completely done, or even if any error happened.

How do You think about such Exclusive Locks pattern ?

Comment: This sounds like a lot of work just to avoid an occasional extra amount of processing because of a client problem.  Is the problem efficiency gain really worth all this extra complication.  Or, why not just fix the client problem?  Rather than thinking of this a exclusive locks, I'd think of it more like a work queue and when a request comes in for a job that is already in progress, you just hook onto the exist job rather than start a duplicate.  If the queue is stored in redis, then all clustered processes can check the queue when they get a new job.

Comment: @jfriend00, The client problem is something considered to be urgently fixed, but also need to be at the safe-side for the server-side.
The queue idea seems great, going to look at things like Kue.